# Why i'm getting errors when creating a new eclipse android project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In Eclipse i'm going to File > New >  Other > Android Application Project
I give a name then click next next next finish  when it's creating the new project i'm getting errors in the console window:

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'

6 errors all in styles.xml

Also i'm getting errors in the MainActivity.java and i didn't change anything didn'nt even open the MainActivity.java yet.

This is the main activity java code i didn't touch or changed anything.

```
package com.example.texttospeech;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

All packages in the android sdk manager already installed.
i'm targeting the project to compile on minimum 7 maximum 18.

First it was 21 so i created new project targeting and compiling 18.

But same errors. I didn't have it before.

I remember i deleted a project name: appcompat_v7 maybe i need this ? If so how to get it ?

Anyway i googled and so far no solution for me.

Comment: The support library jars should be in `sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs`, but it would probably be easier to just recreate a new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the android sdk folder-> extras -> android -> support -> v7

Import the appcompat folder present in v7 folder in eclipse and then add this library to your project. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps , this may help:

1. import android.app.Activity; paste this line in imports
2. Replace ActionBarActivity  with Activity.
3. Remove all methods except onCreate for now.
4. Clean and Rebuilt project.

if problem still persist , restart eclipse.

Comment: oops forgot to mention appcompat_v7 , @Aakash mentioned it anyway.